# Using webpack with an existing requirejs application

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack

I am working with an existing application ([canvas-lms](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms)) that uses RequireJS in its build system. I'm working on a pseudo-standalone application that plugs into Canvas (a "client_app" in Canvas parlance). This is a fontend-only app that makes API calls back to the host Canvas app. The details aren't terribly important for my question - all a client_app needs to do is have a build script that spits out a JS file in a defined place within the Canvas app tree.

I'm trying to use Webpack to build my app instead of RequireJS. Everything works great if I keep all my dependencies self-contained (e.g. npm-install everything I need); however, Canvas already provides many of these dependencies (e.g. React, jQuery), and in jQuery's case, it provides a patched version that I'd like to use instead. This is where I start to have problems.

Getting React to work was easy; Canvas installs it with bower, so I was able to add an `alias` in my [webpack config to point at it](https://github.com/sfu/canvas_spaces_client_app/blob/a8c879646d81bf04951233781ef8ebcc1fbfa78b/webpack.production.js#L37):

```
alias: {
  'react': __dirname + '/vendor/canvas/public/javascripts/bower/react/react-with-addons',
}
```

(`__dirname + /vendor/canvas` is a symlink in my application tree to the host Canvas application's tree)

Where I'm having trouble is trying to load the provided copy of jQuery.

Canvas has the following jQuery structure:

[/public/javascripts/jquery.js](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/d7581b8395fc8b372023b83ce6c3f4f98b5dac72/public/javascripts/jquery.js):

```
define(['jquery.instructure_jquery_patches'], function($) {
  return $;
});
```

[/public/javascripts/jquery.instructure_jquery_patches.js](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/d7581b8395fc8b372023b83ce6c3f4f98b5dac72/public/javascripts/jquery.instructure_jquery_patches.js):

```
define(['vendor/jquery-1.7.2', 'vendor/jquery.cookie'], function($) {
  // does a few things to patch jquery ...
  // ...
  return $;
});
```

[/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/d7581b8395fc8b372023b83ce6c3f4f98b5dac72/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery.cookie.js) -- looks like the standard jquery.cookie plugin, wrapped in an AMD define:

```
define(['vendor/jquery-1.7.2'], function(jQuery) {

jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
    //......
};

});
```

and finally, [/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/d7581b8395fc8b372023b83ce6c3f4f98b5dac72/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js). Not going to paste it in, since it's bog-standard jQuery1.7.2, except that the [AMD define has been made anonymous](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/blob/d7581b8395fc8b372023b83ce6c3f4f98b5dac72/public/javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.js#L9399) -- reverting it to the stock behaviour doesn't make a difference.

I want to be able to do something like `var $ = require('jquery')` or `import $ from 'jquery'` and have webpack do whatever magic, poorly-documented voodoo it needs to do to use `jquery.instructure-jquery-patches`.

I've tried adding the path to `resolve.root` in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  root: [
    __dirname + '/src/js',
    __dirname + '/vendor/canvas/public/javascripts'
  ],
  alias: {
    'react': 'react/addons',
    'react/addons/lib': 'react/../lib'
  }
},
```

This should mean that when I do a `require('jquery')`, it first finds `/public/javascripts/jquery.js`, which defines a module with `instructure_jquery_patches` as a dependency. That falls into `instructure_jquery_patches`, which defines a module with two dependencies (`'vendor/jquery-1.7.2', 'vendor/jquery.cookie'`).

In my main entry point ([index.js](https://github.com/sfu/canvas_spaces_client_app/blob/a8c879646d81bf04951233781ef8ebcc1fbfa78b/src/js/index.js)), I am importing jQuery (also tried a commonjs require, no difference), and trying to use it:

```
import React from 'react';    


import $ from 'jquery';
$('h1').addClass('foo');    

if (__DEV__) {
  require('../scss/main.scss');
  window.React = window.React || React;
  console.log('React: ', React.version);
  console.log('jQuery:', $.fn.jquery);
}
```

Building the bundle with webpack seems to work; there are no errors. When I try to load the page in the browser, though, I'm getting an error from within `jquery.instructure-jquery-patches.js`:

[image]

It would seem that jQuery is not availble within `jquery.instructure-jquery-patches.`

It **is**, however, available in the global scope after the page loads, so jQuery is being evaluated and executed.

[image]

My guess is that I'm running into some sort of requirejs/amd asynchronicity problem, but that's a shot in the dark. I don't know enough about requirejs or amd to know for sure.

Comment: It looks like `jquery.instructure_jquery_patches` isn't exported correctly (You can try to `console.log(require("jquery"))` to vertify it). Check the AMD code in this file. Some older versions of jquery do a check for `define.amd.jQuery` and this is not provided by default. You'll need to provide it (http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#amd).

Comment: @TobiasK. adding `amd: { jQuery: true }` to my webpack config file worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

TobiasK's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617562/using-webpack-with-an-existing-requirejs-application?noredirect=1#comment47404975_29617562) pointed me at needing to add `amd: { jQuery: true }` to my webpack config. Everything is working now.